How to solve an equation with GNU Octave symbolic
I am trying to solve an equation using Octaves symboblic package. I am tinkering with 2 vectors (AB, MC), one of which (AB) is rotated around a point P. The second vector spans from the mid point of vector AB to a fixed point C. C does not rotate around P. I need to get angle of rotation at which AB is orthogonal to MC. My code so far:
pkg load symbolic
syms phi;

A = [2;1];
B = [2;5];
C = [8;5];
P = [2;2];

R = [cos(phi), -sin(phi); sin(phi), cos(phi)];

A_rot = P + R*(A-P);
B_rot = P + R*(B-P);
M = (A+B)/2;
M_rot = P + R*(M-P);

AB_rot = B_rot - A_rot;
MC_rot = C - M_rot;

eqn = dot(MC_rot, AB_rot) == 0;

phi_sol = solve(eqn, phi);
disp(phi_sol);

Octave (9.2.0) comes up with {}(0x0), which is slightly different to what I expected (atan(1/3)). Could some please show me, where I messed things up?

You should disp(eqn) to see if the equation is what you expected. First, you'll see the complex conjugate of phi in eqn, which is the result of dot, which computes the complex dot product, see dot reference. So assume phi real; might be in order. Still, the result is not the one you expected, I don't know where's the problem now - the simplified equation is 3 * cos(phi) - 6 * sin(phi) = 1, and its solutions are those given by octave, I verified by manually substituting sin(phi) and cos(phi) by their tan(phi/2) formulas

Thank you very much for sharing your thoughts! And I have to apologize: the expected solution mentioned above is for P = [3;2]. Your input on getting complex solutions and how to avoid it helps a lot get closer to an closed solution. At least i get results for different values for P which will hopefully get me closer to a closed solution for this stupid problem! Again, thank you very much for the great support!
